# Cookie Auth: Making requests from localhost to live services

Tags: javascript, authentication, localhost, frontend, netflix-zuul

On the platform I'm working on, we are running a React front-end on an Express.js server and when developing on localhost we make calls to our API in our staging environment (from localhost) that is set up on its own domain in the cloud.

We recently set up cookie authentication at the API gateway level (Zuul) in the staging environment.  Since we are running our React app directly on localhost when developing (no Zuul gateway), the app is making calls to the staging API without being authenticating first (no auth cookie).  This is causing our localhost setup to fail on all requests to the API.  I tried a few solutions of injecting tokens into the browser or forcing them to set in the app, but there is still issues with x-origin requests (from localhost to staging).

I'm starting to question our front end dev setup.  Due to the way our API is setup in our multiple live environments, it would be difficult for us to run our API locally and connect to live DB's and middle-tier services. So, I would prefer to find a way to make these requests from localhost to staging work.

We have both server side and client side requests (ajax) that need to hit these services and we are using Axios for the requests. I was thinking that there might be a way to do this by setting `/etc/hosts` and proxying requests, but I'm not sure how this would be done.

Is there a recommended way to tackle the local development setup for front end apps when developing in a micro-service environment where there is authentication?  Should we not be trying to hit a live API when developing locally?  Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One issue and one piece of advice come to mind.

1. You might be hitting a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) issue. Basically if browsers prevent you to hit a different domain to avoid malicious attacks unless the service specifically allows this. For instance, if your frontend app runs in www.mydomain.com/app and your api is in www.mydomain.com/api, there won't be a problem. However, if your frontend app runs on www.mydomain.com and your api is on api.mydomain.com, then your api has to explicitly allow requests coming from www.mydomain.com. The same for localhost since it's seen as a different domain. The config depends on what kind of server you have and you should look for it in its documentation.
2. Most API's nowadays follow the Rest architecture, which makes those APIs stateless. That means that the API doesn't care about the state of any client. Unfortunately, that's not the case of cookies because they have to be kept on both the server side and the client side, so they are stateful. If you want to improve the design of your API, I would recommend you to use tokens, more specifically JSON Web Tokens (JWT). JWTs are stateless and also cheaper to deal with for the server because there's no need to keep track of it. It works based on a digital signature that is originally generated with an encoding algorithm and the validation is done using a decoding algorithm. [Here](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/) a good full comparison.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but we are aware of both of these pieces of advice.  1 - CORS is enabled, 2 - You can store JWT's in cookies.

Comment: 2 - Yes, and it's necessary if server side rendering is necessary. Also, if you are setting cookies from the client side, make sure you are setting the path. Otherwise, you'll run into troubles.